# Jasmine+Karma: ActivatedRoute spy not not getting called

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-test

I have an Angular component that uses ActivateRoute

```
getFlavorAndService(): void {
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {

      const flavor: string = params.flavor;
      const service: string = params.service;
      const platform: string = params.platform;

      if (platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
      } else {
        this.platform = this._dataService.DEFAULT_PLATFORM;
      }

      if (flavor) {
        this.flavor = flavor;
      } else {
        this.flavor = this._dataService.DEFAULT_FLAVOR;
      }

      if (service) {
          this.service = service;
      } else {
        this.service = this._dataService.DEFAULT_SERVICE;
      }
    });
  }
```

I am trying to test `getFlavorAndService()` method in the following way:

```
it('Test', () => {

      dataService.attributeSearchEnabled = false;
      dataService.endpointSearchEnabled = false;

      const spy = spyOn(activatedRoute, 'params').and.returnValue(of({
        flavor: 'by-fund',
        service: 'profile_benchmarks',
        platform: 'on-prem',
      }));

      component.getFlavorAndService();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      expect(component.platform).toBe('on-prem');
      expect(component.service).toBe('profile_benchmarks');
      expect(component.flavor).toBe('by-fund');
    });
```

I have also created a stub for ActivatedRoute:

```
class ActivatedRouteStub {

  get params() {
    return of({});
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return of({});
  }
}
```

My test cases are failing and none of the expectations are working fine. flavor, service and platform are taking the default values provided in the class and not the values passed using `spyOn(activatedRoute, 'params').and.returnValue(of({....`

I have also provided `ActivatedRouteStub` in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` method

```
{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRouteStub }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
const spy = spyOn(activatedRoute, 'params').and.returnValue(of({
```

try using this:

```
const spy = spyOnProperty(activatedRoute, 'params', 'get').and.returnValue(of({
```

**spyOn -> spyOnProperty**

Check the docs [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#spyOnProperty).